# ugprade cakephp 3 to latest version

Tags: cakephp

i have cakephp3.3 windows and i need to upgrade to cakephp3.6. Checking the docs i see there is no tool available. Checking the migration guides i am not seeing any issues with my code in cake3.3 with newer versions.

Do i simply create a new instance of cake3.6 and create models,controllers again using bake and then copy over code to see if this works? what is an efficient way

The docs in cakephp are not clear on this process. do i upgrade to 3.4 then 3.5,3.6?

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-x-migration-guide.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use composer.**

For Windows, you can download it from [here](https://github.com/composer/windows-setup/releases/). After installation, locate `composer.json` file in your CakePHP application directory, and look for "require" part, and update line regarding CakePHP as follows:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6",
    "cakephp/cakephp": "3.6.*",
    ....
}
```

Then, in command line, navigate to your CakePHP installation directory and fire `composer update`. After a while you should have your CakePHP upgraded.

More info about updating to new version can be found in docs:
[Keeping up to date with latest CakePHP changes](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#keeping-up-to-date-with-the-latest-cakephp-changes)

Comment: sorry i am completely and utterly confused with composer. Whenever i see the words composer and setup i go weak at the knees as composer is awkward! ii install composer and look for composer.json of which i find dozens in my application. what an earth am i supposed to do? they reside in vendor cakephp folder mostly.  I am just confused!!

Comment: The one that you need will be directly in your cakephp installation directory (directory that contains bin, src, vendor folders).

Comment: there is nothing in bin folder, vendor has dozens of composer.json which one  exactly??

Comment: sorry i see what you mean. There is nothing in the install directory . there is no composer.json as it doesnt exist after installing composer

Comment: If you do not have this file in your app directory, that means that it was probably deleted at some point. So you should create new CakePHP 3.6 project (use composer for it - you won't understand it if you will not use it ;) and just copy src directory from your 3.3 project.

Comment: what about the app and webroot folder files, do i copy them over? bootstrap? there are a few files outside src dir

Comment: Copy over src, webroot and config, and other files that are vital for your app.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution was given which was to install a new instance of cakephp and just copy over scr folder and other relevant code in the new instance. This is more work but the conversion from 3.3 to 3.6 isnt very  clean with a composer update